# Deductive proof for the unicorn scenario

Tags: natural-deduction

(p ⇒ q) ∧ (¬p ⇒ ¬q ∧r)

(q ∨r) ⇒ s

s ⇒ t

Therefore,

t

my efforts.

1   (p ⇒ q) ∧ (¬p ⇒ ¬q ∧r        premise

2   (q ∨r) ⇒ s                  premise

3   s ⇒ t                       premise

4 p                 assumption

5 q                 from 1 & 4 ⇒ elim (modus ponens)

6 q∨r               from 2 & 5, v Intro

7 s                     from 2 & 6, ⇒ elim (modus ponens)

8 t                 from 3 & 7, ⇒ elim (modus ponens)

9 ¬p                assumption

10 ¬q ∧r                from 1 & 9 ⇒ elim (modus ponens)

11 r                from 10 ∧ Elim

12 q∨r              from 11 ∨intro

13 s                from 2 & 12, ⇒ elim (modus ponens)

14 t                    from 3 & 13, ⇒ elim (modus ponens)

Comment: What is your question? And what do you mean with "each step"? The second line does not follow from the first line, no does the third line follow from the second etc.

Comment: Already asked as [validity-of-deductive-proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210112/validity-of-deductive-proof).

Comment: Hi Tim , apologies for the confusion, the first three lines are my premises, or what i am lead to believe, i need to derive to the conclusion t. I am learning this topic at uni, maths is not really my strongest point.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, just to confirm is that the correct answer?

Comment: hi tim. i have now provided my working out, i know its wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deductive Proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209162/deductive-proof)

Comment: Yes, very funny indeed... And in the last week we have seen another couple of copies of the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1$\;(p \to q) \land (\lnot p \to (¬q \land r))$ $\quad$ premise

2$\;(q\lor r)\to s$ $\quad$ premise

3$\;s\to t$. $\quad $ premise

---

4 $\;(p\to q)\quad$ (1, $\land$-elim)

5 $\;\lnot p \to (\lnot q \land r)\quad (1, \land$-elim)

6 $\;p \lor \lnot p\quad$ (tautology: Assuming Law of the excluded middle)

7 $\qquad$ Assume $p.\;\;$  (assumption)

8 $\qquad\qquad q\quad $ from $4, 7$, elim modus ponens

9$\qquad\qquad q\lor r\quad $ from 8 $\lor$-intro

10 $\qquad\qquad s\quad$      from 2&9 elim modus ponens

11 $\qquad\qquad t\quad$     from 3&10 elim modus ponens

12 $\qquad p\to t\quad$   from $7-11$, $\to$-intro

10 $\qquad$ Assume $\lnot p\quad $ Assumption

11 $\qquad\qquad \lnot q\land r\quad$ 5, 10, modus ponens

12 $\qquad\qquad r\quad$ 11, $\land$-elim

13 $ \qquad \qquad q\lor r\quad $ 12 $\,\lor$-Intro

14$\qquad\qquad s\quad $ from 2, 13, modus ponens

15$\qquad\qquad t\quad$  from 3, 14, modus ponens

16 $\qquad\lnot p \to t\quad $ from 10-15, conditional introduction.

17 $\;(p\lor \lnot p)\to t$

18 $\;t$

Now,  you can refer to your text and notes, and the rules of inference you've learned, to justify each step.

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck on the reason for any of the above steps.

Comment: hi could you possibly label each of the steps, i know its a long stretch, i know some of laws applied on various steps but i'm not 100% sure

Comment: Yes, you've got it! Although 4 in my sketch is the assumption p, so 1+4 $\to 5$ via modus ponens.

Comment: on line 5 you used v intro?

Comment: would it possible to edit your answer and leave the laws applied on each line?

Comment: you got it!  And with $q\lor r$ along with the second premise, we get s....

Comment: if i was edit you answer with each step annotated, could you be able to confirm it for me?

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to do that!  Just let me know in a comment when you're done.  And maybe we should start with 1, 2, 3, being the premises.

Comment: yes i will label it and you can check it for me, thanks, give me 10 mins !

Comment: hi @amWhy is this correct so far?

Comment: So far so good, just had to correct the lines to refer to for $6$

Comment: thanks, i will finish it off now

Comment: is this finished now?

Comment: thanks can you please please annotate the rest for me?

Comment: I did some additional annotations, your edits were rejected by a bot before I had a chance to check them.

Comment: yes i was confused as to why my edits didn't go through

Comment: if you can annotate the last 6 lines, you will have saved my life, thanks for the help!